# Problems with palindrome in c

Tags: c, gcc

[A C program to find if the input number is palindrome or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UoFb.png)

[The problem as I see it is that the even numbered powers come out strange. Can anyone please tell me what the problem could be?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08sYL.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to provide your code, and not just have a link to an image of your code.

Comment: Read the documentation for `pow` and notice that there is no integer version.

Answer (score 3):

The `pow` function is returning incorrect values right. instead of using the `pow` in the code multiply 10 with the sum to get the output

```
remainder = n%10;
reversed = reversed*10 + remainder;
n /= 10;
```

The best way to get accurate results with `pow` function would be to use doubles as much as you can. Like most functions using integers for large floating point operations tends to leave you with inaccurate results

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `pow` you are using returns incorrect values. For integer powers of 10, it ought to return exactly 1, 10, 100, 1000, et cetera, but it returns values slightly different. Furthermore, when it returns a value slightly under an integer and that value is converted from floating-point to `int`, it is truncated, so the result of `int x = pow(10, 3)` may be 999 rather than 1000.

Do not use this `pow` for exponentiating ten. You can write a simple integer replacement for `pow` (with another name, of course), or you can rewrite your code to avoid relying on exponentiating ten. (Working iteratively, with 1, 10, 100, 1000, and so on, is often better—simply multiplying by ten at each step instead of exponentiating to calculate the power.)